SPFX get Microsoft Outlook room events using Graph API
I am building an SPFx app and I need to read the rooms and their events from Outlook, our company has 25 conference rooms that can be used to book events in a SharePoint calendar, we need to make sure the room is available in outlook and also be able create the event in outlook when submitted in the SharePoint form
I was able to get the list of all the rooms using the SharePoint context and querying the Microsoft Graph API like this:
 const [outlookRooms, setOutlookRooms] = useState<any[]>([]);

 React.useEffect(() =>{
const context = props.context;

      context.msGraphClientFactory
      .getClient('3')
      .then((client: MSGraphClientV3): void => {      
        client
          .api('/places/microsoft.graph.room')
          .get((response: any, error: any) => {
            console.log(response);
            console.log(error);
             setOutlookRooms(response);            
   
        });
      });

 },[]);

that part is working fine but when I try to get the room events I am getting a 404, this is my code for getting the room events:
 const [roomEvents, setRoomEvents] = useState<any[]>([]);  

React.useEffect(() =>{
const context = props.context;

context.msGraphClientFactory
    .getClient('3')
    .then((client: MSGraphClientV3): void => {      
      client
        .api('/groups/roomid/calendarView?startDateTime=2024-01-01T19:00:00-08:00&endDateTime=2024-06-01T19:00:00.00-08:00')
        .get((response: any) => {
          setRoomEvents(response.value);            
          console.log(response);
      })
      
      ;
    });
 },[]);


I couldn't find a way to get the events for rooms directly from the SPFX, what I end up doing was to create an Azure Function to get the events from Outlook, then I can call the azure function from the SPFX app, you have to enable CORS in the azure function to accept SharePoint calls, the azure function looks like this:
import { app, HttpRequest, HttpResponseInit } from "@azure/functions";
import axios from "axios";
import { Context } from "vm";

const tenantId = "mytenantid";
const clientId = "appclientid";
const clientSecret = "appclientsecret";
const scopes = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";

export async function GetEvents(req: HttpRequest, context: Context): Promise<HttpResponseInit> {
    context.log(`Http function processed request for url "${req.url}"`);   
    
    
    const startDate = req.query.get('startdate') || await req.text();    
    const endDate = req.query.get('enddate') || await req.text();
    const roomEmail = req.query.get('roomemail') || await req.text();       

        if(startDate ==='' || endDate ==='' || roomEmail ===''){
            return { body: 'Parameters missing startdate: ' + startDate + 'enddate: ' +endDate+ 'room: '+ roomEmail}
        }       

        const params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.append('client_id', clientId);
        params.append('client_secret', clientSecret);
        params.append('scope', scopes);
        params.append('grant_type', 'client_credentials');

        let loginResponse = await axios.post(`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/oauth2/v2.0/token`, params);
        
        if (loginResponse.status == 200) {
            let accessToken: string = loginResponse.data.access_token;

            let getPlaceResponse = await axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{useridwithpermissionstorooms}/calendar/getSchedule`,
                headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken },
                data: {
                    Schedules: [roomEmail],
                    StartTime: {
                        dateTime: startDate,
                        timeZone: "America/Denver"
                    },
                    EndTime: {
                        dateTime: endDate,
                        timeZone: "America/Denver"
                    },
                    availabilityViewInterval: "30"
                }
            });

            if(getPlaceResponse.status == 200){
                context.res = getPlaceResponse.data.value[0].scheduleItems;
            }
            else{
                context.res = {
                    status: 500,
                    body: {
                        message: "Get Schedule Error"
                    }
                };
            }            
        }
        else {
            context.res = {
                status: 500,
                body: {
                    message: "Auth Error"
                }
            };
        }  

   let result = JSON.stringify(context.res);
    return {body: result};

};

app.http('GetEvents', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: GetEvents
});


I would use emailAddress instead of room id and call users endpoint
/users/{room_email_address}/calendarView?startDateTime=2024-01-01T19:00:00-08:00&endDateTime=2024-06-01T19:00:00.00-08:00'


I tried that too but I get a 403 token empty error

@AzielArcila Error 403 indicates that you don't have a permission to read calendar. How do you authenticate? On behalf of user or as a daemon service? Check you if granted Calendar.ReadBasic permission

I did granted Calendar.ReadBasic and Calendar.Write permissions and neither seems to work, I also granted permissions to the user and rooms and nothing seems to work, thanks!
